# Can there be a real solution to the square root of -1?

Tags: arithmetic, fake-proofs

Basically what the title says:

Can there be a real solution to the square root of $-1$ (or any negative number in fact) or is it defined to be unreal?

Because of this: $$ \begin{align} \sqrt{-1} & = (-1)^\frac 12 \\[6pt]
& = (-1)^\frac 24 \\[6pt]
& = \sqrt[4]{(-1)^2} \\[6pt]
&= \sqrt[4]{1} \\[6pt]
&= 1
\end{align}$$

Comment: I truly wish that we called it an unreal number.

Comment: $\sqrt[4]{1} = i$, also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, unfortunately. Your logic seems to imply that $1^2 = -1$ which isn't the case.

It also implies that root 4 of 1 is only 1.

This is kinda why complex numbers were invented.

Now, you could invent your own number system and call them "real numbers" or re-define the square root to mean something else.